# Highstock: Property 'firePointEvent' of object #<Object> is not a function

Tags: javascript, highcharts

When fire a click on a serie, I get the next error : **Uncaught TypeError: Property 'firePointEvent' of object # is not a function**.

In Highstock.js v1.3.1 (2013-04-15) on line 9575 :

```
// the series click event
fireEvent(hoverPoint.series, 'click', extend(e, {
    point: hoverPoint
}));
```

Until there, `hoverPoint` exist and have real values, but don't have yet `firePointEvent` method.

```
// the point click event
hoverPoint.firePointEvent('click', e);
```

On this next line, `hoverPoint` still exist and do have a `firePointEvent` method, but all its attributes are null. So it throws the error :/

What's the problem here?

Comment: Create jsFiddle example, please.

Comment: See the fiddle example in my post. Will this error be remove from highchart in a near future ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could reproduce this problem. You can see it in  [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/49MMU/).

1. click on the chart background (it removes the line)
2. then click on the series (the line is back and it trigger the error)

I found a workaround for this, you have to set a little timeout so the click event and the update process won't happen in the same call.

I guess the `update()` makes the **hoverPoint** object to be altered, causing the **firePointEvent** property to be `null` at the end of the process.

Here the workaround : ([in JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/49MMU/2/) )

```
plotOptions: {
        series: {
            events: {
                click: function(event) {
                    var that = this;
                    setTimeout( function(){
                        that.update({
                            lineWidth: 1,
                        });
                    }, 20);

                }
            }
        }
},
```